# How Oracle decide which join type to use

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, join

i have 2 tables let's say *table a* and *table b*
*table a* stored like 6G and *table b* 1G

when i use table a inner join table b the explain plan use **Nest loop** and cost like 3mins to finish but our hardware is good enough for **hash join**. so i use hint to force it use hash and the query cost like 1 min.

My Question is: how Oracle decide this, where the explain come from?
at inner join, if the right choice is Nest Loop join. how Oracle decide which table to join. i mean there are cost difference if the order of join changed, how would Oracle make a right decision?

and if Oracle choose wrong like above it use Nest Loop how to make it right? i mean not use hint to force it, just change something to help it do the right decision

I've been asked this question months ago and i googled it and nothing helpful

Comment: The place to start is the documentation:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25178_01/server.1111/e16638/optimops.htm#i51523.

Comment: This question is too broad/general to have a specific answer. You can discover a great deal about the optimizer here https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/